# Two 200V outputs on 1 DC electronic Load

Tags: load

I have a product with two 230V outputs. I want to test if the product is also working correctly under high load(2kW on each output) I have an electronic load with 1 output. Can I just connect both outputs to the electronic load and set the load at 2kW? Or do I need to set the load to 4kW? I am a software engineer so I am not totally into this kind of stuff.

edit:
the outputs are 230V DC instead of 200V. The input is 1 phase 230V rms. it is connected to fuse and after that a triac is placed . again another fuse and then the output.

The same holds for the other connector but then with a different phase.

I got a DIB with bridge rectifiers on it. this converts the outputs to 230VDC and after that the load is connected.

I can change this DIB. So maybe an idea is to use a 2 phase bridge rectifier to make from the two phases DC voltage and then put a load on the outputs?

Comment: Whether you can do it *at all* with the equipment you have depends on more details that you need to specify. What kind of outputs are these? Is it a power supply, battery charger, amplifier, welder, what? What are all the electrical specifications of the outputs - in particular, are they isolated, or are (which) terminals grounded? Please [edit] your question with more information.

Comment: The first and foremost question is: Is it possible to connect the two 200V outputs of your product together without damaging the product? If so, try the load. If not, then you certainly need two separate loads to test the device. That's it. Question answered. Only you know that at the moment. Without further information on the outputs, it is a guessing game. Good luck for everyone!

Comment: Even if the OP can connect the two outputs without damage, it doesn't mean that they will share current equally or at all.  (Though they'll probably droop share to some degree at high loads)  Loop interaction is also possible and could cause instability.

Comment: Jonh D added good points to consider. Nevertheless, the answer to the question has to be made in consecutive steps: 1) Can the outputs be connected? No -> 2 loads are mandatory. 2) Do the outputs share equally to the load? No -> 2 loads necessary. 3) Is one load at the connected outputs able to test what the OP wants to test at all? No -> 2 loads. Etc. This is what I wanted to point out. As long as we do not know anything about the outputs, we can only rise issues that theoretically may happen but cannot give any reasonable answer.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I did an edit on my question. hopefully it is more clear. How can i check if I am able to connect two outputs together?

Comment: Maybe you should let the hardware engineers play around with 230 V**D**C.  DC power at these voltages is not like 12 VDC the adorable little Mogwai.  At this voltage DC power cannot be bargained with, cannot be reasoned with, does not show pity or remorse or fear, and that's even before you feed it after midnight!